# where's the documentation for NodeJS's system module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I see `require("sys")` used a lot, and I see that there is [a CommonJS spec for a system module](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/System) but [some code that I see](https://github.com/usenode/use.no.de/blob/master/server.js) uses the module like so `require("sys").error(e);` and error does not appear to be listed in the CommonJS spec, so I'm wondering where I can find the documentation for the system module used by NodeJS, since [I'm not seeing it in the NodeJS documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/all.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ah it looks like the module was renamed to be `util` so the documentation is at http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/all.html#util

---

**Update:** *(merged from a subsequent answer from the same user)*

The source is here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/sys.js

But I'm hoping that there is actual documentation..