# Node.js doesn't work on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I setup a ubuntu14.04 server on Amazon EC2 recently,
when I install the nodejs using shell:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

It says nodejs is already the newest version.
In order to check successful Node installation ,I write this in a test.js file

```
var sys = require("sys");  
sys.puts("Hello World");
```

when I try

```
node test.js
```

I got nothing in the shell.strange..someohelp?

I follow the offical demo

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

save it as server.js try to run it with node server.js   doesn't work...

But it works well in my local ubuntu server machine. So I guess it's may be an Amazon's problem?

I see this thread:

[Can't connect to Node web-server hosted on Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235466/cant-connect-to-node-web-server-hosted-on-amazon-ec2?rq=1)

and it's not work on my problem too.After I allow all traffic from everywhere on all ports.Still get the same problem.

BTW,I'm using PUTTY to connect to the server.

It's right that ubuntu 14.04 have a diffent version of nodejs.So I download the .tar.gz file from the offical website the unpack it , and run

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Then it works for me....

Comment: seems to be require("util") now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227701/wheres-the-documentation-for-nodejss-system-module

Comment: Why not check the version that is currently installed? `node --version`. Posting that value may also help explain why there was no output from your test.js.

Comment: I try node --version but no output in the shell,that't the problem,cause when I try sudo apt-get again.it tells me the nodejs is already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that some versions of Ubuntu including 14.04 need to have a different package installed for nodejs. There is a conflict with the node process and you're not actually run node but some other application.

To resolve the problem install nodejs using `sudo apt get install nodejs-legacy`. After doing that you should see a version returned if you run `node --version`.

Answer (score 1):

node != nodejs.  Try running:
    nodejs test.js

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```js
sudo node test.js
```

It worked for me